'DWV' PVC pipes ~ Is it ok to have an open inlet in the basement?
Our basement has a openings in the PVC drain-waste-vent (DWV) system, for a washer and water softener to drain.
I just realized there's no check valve on this or anything to prevent a sewage backup (in the neighborhood) from backflowing into my basement.
Should this have a check valve?  Is this normal?

In this basement, the sewage pipe to the street is several feet off the floor, as you can see.
The pink arrow on the left shows a tube from the water softener, which flushes water periodically.



For a backup, it should be on the main drain.  A check valve on the small pipe will just cause the backup to go up higher.  I know since we had a just finish basement after ten years of a dry basement.  I think you might need caps on those lines to prevent sewer gas(in case the trap dries out).

The upper open pipe has something draining into it - if it has water coming in year round, the trap is unlikely to dry out, and there is no need to do anything there.
The lower open pipe for a washing machine is designed to have an air gap for the drain. It looks kind of high to to me, but washing machines will give you a maximum height difference between the machine and the drain. If you don't use it, sure cap it. There is plenty of height to cut the cap off if needed.
Ultimately, as long as the trap stays filled, you don't need to do anything.
